# Open a text file with a given path in x86 MASM assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, irvine32

The program should take the file path as input then displays the text inside it. But my code just open a text file in a debug folder it can't open text file in an other folders with a given path.

This is a part of the code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
INCLUDE macros.inc

BUFFER_SIZE = 50

.data
buffer BYTE BUFFER_SIZE DUP(?)
filename    BYTE 80 DUP(0)
fileHandle  HANDLE ?

.code
main PROC

; Let user input a filename.
mWrite "Enter an input filename: "
mov edx,OFFSET filename
mov ecx,SIZEOF filename
call    ReadString

; Open the file for input.
mov edx,OFFSET filename
call    OpenInputFile
mov fileHandle,eax
```

Comment: Do you have an example of running this code, and typing actual input like `c:\foo\bar.txt`?  Copy/paste from a terminal where you ran it, along with a directory listing showing that it's a valid path, to make this a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks..i was writing  the path with out the file name ..sorry for my stupidity